# Would it be useful to create a generic subclass of DataContractSerializer that takes a type parameter?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I have used the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class in the past and found that it seems quite common to create generic versions of the Serilize and Deserialize methods. I didn't have any previous code to hand recently so I searched for some and found this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233908/Xml-serialization-using-generics#section2.

For using the XmlSerializer it looks quite useful.  I started doing some testing but then realised that I'm using [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) type which is not Serializable.  So I searched online again and found the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) class which it turns out does support the TimeSpan type.  So the actual code should all work fine now.

I started to wonder about creating a generic version of the DataContractSerializer class in the same way it appears to be common to do with the XmlSerializer.  After searching online I've not been able to find any examples.  Currently I think it would be possible to create a generic version but I'm wondering if there is any point.

Can anyone that's useful the DataContractSerializer tell me if they've come across this please?  Could it be that I'm over engineering a solution before I've even tried to use the standard classes?

My idea was to create a generic wrapper that could be put into a common utilities/tools assembly that I'm going to try and start building for future work.

Edit:
I also found this sample:http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=datacontractserializer+generic+wrapper&source=bl&ots=ChCqGuHXIs&sig=-uMLuqd7B1bUj6uWZfTQcScLfe0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ypw_UdjvGYesPdKqgPAG&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA

Though I found that it doesn't compile because it doesn't implement the required methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you could do that.  You can actually write a non-generic version as well; here are two functions which do this:

```
public static void Write<T>(T data)
{
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        dcs.WriteObject(stream, data);
    }
}

public static void Write(object data)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(data.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        dcs.WriteObject(stream, data);
    }
}
```

Overall, it allows you to save a few lines of code, and gives you a consistent interface, so as long as you write it properly (and don't just copy-paste this ;)) I think it's a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: That's what I though plus using the type parameter for the read and write means you will always use the same type for the same object. I was just unsure since I couldn't find an example online.